# How to uninstall kernel with its modules?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, kvm-virtualization

I'm doing my project in ubuntu on kernel version 3.10.48. But due to compatible problems, we had to change the version (recompile the kernel) to 3.17.6. Now, as I had assigned 50 GB to ubuntu only 9 GB is left and I will run out of space if I add few more packages. How do remove the previous kernel modules of version 3.10.48 as they are not required here after?

Comment: Don't you install modules with `dkms`? I guess uninstallation will be possible thru `dkms remove`.

Comment: You might also check to see how many old kernels you have installed. Ubuntu doesn't automatically purge old kernels when there's an update, so most systems have several previous kernel releases hanging around after the latest updates. Removing the entire outdated kernel packages (retaining the latest stable one) could free up quite a bit of space.

Comment: If I try using commands available after googling, they don't work. Like I tried for viewing linux images but it just showed me the linux images that were installed while installing ubuntu which I don't want to remove. While recompilation there are commands like make install_modules and make install where the actual installation of modules start. I want to remove them by uninstalling those like we do for normal packages.Please suggest me ways to remove those modules

Comment: I want to uninstall the kernel as in want to free up the space, remove stuff related to that kernel and after doing these and since we have uninstalled the kernel, it should not be visible in the grub menu as well.

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/06/compile-linux-kernel/ http://www.ramkitech.com/2012/04/how-to-compile-kernel-step-by-step.html   I followed these two links to recompile new kernel. Don't know about dkms.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to enter this in the terminal:

```
     sudo apt-get -y --force-yes purge linux-shim-efi shim-amd64 shim-amd64-generic
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: what are these packages ? I found them nowhere

Answer (score 0):

the total kernel modules size is here of 200M. It is not htat much

If you are looking for space you can remove the downloaded package if you don't need them anymore.

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

or if you want to more aggressive of the clean-up

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

you have compiled yourself the kernel, you can remove the builded file which can take some space also.

There might otheer ways to get some space.

Comment: Using sudo apt-get autoclean, what all packages will be removed? You have said that it will remove all downloaded packages. But the basic would also get removed or they just will be downgraded or anything?

Comment: I tried with these commands, but none of them worked... It searched for dependencies but didn't remove any packages and I still have only 9GB left...